# Refreshing gridview after deleting a record from gridview issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi i have this issue that after i delete some record from grid-view the record still exsit in the grid-view although the record is removed from the database

the record disappear from grid view only after i refresh the page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gridpurchase.DataSource = s.getpurchase();
        gridpurchase.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Delete code

```
protected void gridpurchase_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

                string PurchaseID = row.Cells[6].Text;
                GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                Int32 rowind = gvRow.RowIndex;

                switch (commandName)
                {    
                    case "DeletePurchase":
                        if (s.DelPurchase(Convert.ToInt32(PurchaseID)))
                        {
                                string msg = "alert('Purchase Deleted Successfully');";
                               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');window.location.href='" + Request.RawUrl + "';", true); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string msg = "Purchase Not Deleted";
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');window.location.href='" + Request.RawUrl + "';", true);

                        }
                        break;  
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error:" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

aspx code

```
                       <asp:GridView ID="gridpurchase" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gridpurchase_RowCommand"  runat="server" DataKeyNames="Purchase_ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" CssClass="table table-bordered text-nowrap">

                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditPurchase" Text=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record ?');" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandName="DeletePurchase" Text="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Print" ShowHeader="False">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton20" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="PrintInvoice" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" Text=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-default " />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Purchase ID" DataField="Purchase_ID" InsertVisible="False" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Purchase_ID">
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Purchase Date" HeaderText="Purchase Date">

                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                &quot;No records found&quot;
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post the relevant aspx code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to call DataBind to update the grid after deleting the record in the database.

Comment: If you put the two lines of your page load code after your deletion code, the grid content is not updated?

Comment: @Ayman It will work. Where do you put this code? Put it right after the switch statement.

Comment: @Ayman - I am as surprised as you are. Is the GridView in an UpdatePanel? If not, you can check in the debugger what happens when you bind the data after deleting the row. If you monitor the DataBound event, you can see if the content of the grid has actually changed or not. You will know if the problem is the display not being refreshed or if the deleted row is still in the grid.